# Force Omniauth/OAuth to ignore browser cache and reauthenticate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, omniauth

So I've run into the following unintended behavior when setting up OAuth with Omniauth in my Rails app.

When a user has previously authenticated to a OAuth provider (Facebook for example), the credentials are stored somewhere in the browser. If a different user tries to make an OAuth request in the same browser, it uses the stored data from the first user!

Is there a way to force the OAuth request to not use stored credentials and make the user authorize the app every time?

I've tried adding the `no-cache` headers to the controller using the code below, but it didn't do anything of course, as the request is to the providers OAuth endpoint and not anywhere internal to my app.

```
  before_filter :set_cache_buster

  def set_cache_buster
    p "CACHE BBBBUSTED!"
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0,must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
    request.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0,must-revalidate"
    request.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    request.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
  end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem, but with google_oauth2. In fact, I wish to let user decide if he wants to reset automatic login. How did you solve the issue ?

Comment: @FernandoFabreti these are my google_oauth2 Omniauth settings that seem to work: ``` :scope => "userinfo.email,userinfo.profile,plus.me",
    :approval_prompt=>"force",
    :access_type=>"offline" ```

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, you login using Facebook credentials through Omniauth. And after you leave your application, the user stays authenticated with *Facebook* (not your app, not OAuth, so dumping your cookies won't help). So, next time when you try to log in to your app (click on the "login with facebook" link/button), Facebook doesn't ask anything (the user is already authorized with facebook, the application permissions are also in place) and simply returns the credentials, so your app goes forward and lets your previous user in.

I guess, what you need is to log out from Facebook each time you log out from the app. Check this railscast, for example, on one way to deal with that: http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication?view=asciicast. But you'll have to deal separately with every provider (twitter, ...). Or you can try finding & clearing facebook's  persistent cookie (afaik, facebook use persistent cookies to implement "remember me", but I'm not an expert and I never had a need to research it) in your browser.

My only other comment is that in production such behavior is *desirable* - as long as it is the same OS-user and that user remains authenticated in twitter/facebook etc your app also assumes it is the same user. If you need to change the user - logout/login in your OS, or else you give access to the next guy to this app, facebook, and all other web services where "remember me" is set and you haven't logged out. For auto-testing you shouldn't have this problem at all, since cookies - both session and persistent - don't persist between the tests.

I can see how that can be a problem for manual testing, though. But manual is manual - just manually logout from facebook and you should be ok.

All this is just my guess based on your description. So, no guarantees, but hope that helps, at least to some point.

Answer (score 0):

With facebook you can [configure omniauth-facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#configuring) to force reauthentication by setting `auth_type` to `reauthenticate`.